# Compromised RSA key - unsure of the scope of the issue

Tags: ssh, security, rsa

So, I have no experience here, but what sorts of problems can be caused by a compromised private RSA key? Is this even that big of a deal? I'm getting very little specific info on Google. :(

Comment: It **ENTIRELY** depends on what the RSA is being used to protect!

Comment: Do not use compromised private key for anything. Create a new pair.

Comment: Based on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/42680/compromised-private-rsa-key?s=d6edde96-a9f3-4461-b3bc-48e5c55c549e (which this is a duplicate of) I am assuming that this RSA is used in some sort of web context, but you need to be a lot more specific.

Comment: Yeah, I posted it there before I realized there was a better community for this sort of question. I'll delete it there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on **what the private key was used for**.

- If it was a SSH key used to log into remote servers, then anyone who has the key could **log into the owner's account** on those servers – exactly as if their password was compromised.
- If it was a SSH "host key", or if it belonged to an X.509 certificate used for SSL, then anyone who has the key could **pretend to be that server** whose key was stolen – see [man-in-the-middle attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) for description.
- If it was a PGP key or an X.509 certificate used for S/MIME, then it could be used to **decrypt mail** received by the key's owner, or to **[sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) forged messages** that pretend to be from the key's owner. PGP keys, as well as "code-signing" X.509 certificates, are also frequently used to sign computer programs, so those would be possible to falsify as well.
- If the key belonged to an X.509 "certificate authority" certificate, then somebody could use it to **create new certificates for any name** – for example, they could create a SSL certificate for `*.google.com` and use it in a MitM attack (see above).
- etc.

I should also mention that RSA is only one of several key types, just the most common one; DSA or ECDSA keys are also used for the same purposes. See [public-key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) for a general overview.

Comment: I realize this was a stupid question (hence the flurry of down-voting) but I really appreciate you taking the time to answer. Thanks.